# Unusual android activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I wrote a game, and in logs from market i sometimes see following pattern:

```
06:02:13:835|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnCreate
06:02:13:932|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnStart
06:02:14:010|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnResume
...
06:09:27:688|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnPause
06:09:28:895|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#3.OnCreate
06:09:29:159|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#3.OnStart
06:09:29:319|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#3.OnResume
06:09:29:551|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnStop
06:09:29:596|INFO|1|MainActivity|MainActivity#2.OnDestroy
```

MainActivity instance #3 is created and started before MainActivity instance #2 is destroyed. What does this pattern mean ? Why does new instance start before previous has been destroyed ?

Obviously i don't create activity by hand. Users simply start game by tapping icon(at least i hope so).

Activity has singleTask launch mode.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onDestroy callback is not guaranteed to be called. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> onDestroy() = The final call you receive before your activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can
>   distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: onDestroy was called. But later than i wanted.
For example i open file in start, close in stop. 
Bad thing is that i cannot open same file in new activity while it is locked by previous instance. So i want to understand this lifecycle pattern, how can i avoid it

Comment: You need to "clean stuff" (like a file lock) in the onPause() callback, that is the method called when your activity goes in background (inclusively when you switch to another activity). Notice that onPause() is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: I want to understand the nature of that flow. How can i reproduce it ?
If i reproduce that issue - it will solve my issues. 
Cleaning stuff on pause is very expensive for a big game. Any minimizing of app will take much longer. Also opening facebook or any other activity will pause my main one, and will introduce multisecond lag. I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: @Grigory to understand the Activity life cycle you should read the basic documentation, which is very straightforward. About releasing resources that other applications could need, you should do it in onPause because that's how Android works and you should follow the pattern. [Here you have more information about that](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html#Pause). About your initial question, you have been answered. Please accept it, and eventually ask another question about any other specific doubt.

Comment: You haven't answered my question about the reason why OS starts new activity before destroying previous one. U said that ondestroy can be skipped. But onDestroy is called in my scenario. And the main thing in my Q is that activity is singleTask. But if you want another answered question - no problem. Get an answer mark:)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your application has two activities. Then this would be the life cycle

[image]

**onDestroy** will be called if you explicitly call finish(); yourself or like the example if you press Back button because pressing back key actually provokes finish() method on your activity, and it causes your activity to be paused->stopped->destroyed

Comment: But I have only one activity with singleTask launch mode. How does system create and start another instance of it before even stopping first one?

Comment: I think this link can help you to resolve your problem with a singleTask Activity. In the document say that SingleTask doesn't seem to work as described in the android document but show a way to do it http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en